# Is it possible for us to make use of version labels?

Tags: discussion, answers

There’s a post on meta [talking about version labels](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370640/version-labels-for-answers). While this feature was obviously created with Stack Overflow in mind, some people have said that it could be used on other sites.

Question:

**Should politics SE have version labels, and if so, what should we use them for?**

Comment: Can you give an example of how you think it would work on this site? I am not seeing how we would use it.

Comment: @JoeW Neither am I, that’s why I asked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am going to say this is not something that would apply to us as I don't see any of our tags as being able to take advantage of different versions.

Comment: [trump-impeachment]? :P

Comment: Well, there's Ukraine 1.0 and Ukraine 2.0 (now with 100% less Crimea) I guess

Comment: @Machavity I don’t understand.

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica Russia redrew the borders of Ukraine a few years ago. So... technically would fit into a versioning scheme. Was more making a joke